# pyjwt raises an error on decode

Tags: python, jwt, pypy, pyjwt

I am using [PyJWT](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt) to generate and validate JWT in Python. Running [pypy3 v2.4](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/release-pypy3-2.4.0.html).

Simply trying to `encode` and `decode` a JWT similar to the example in the GitHub repo. I am getting the following error when decoding:

```
    decoded = jwt.decode(encoded, secret, algorithm='HS256')
File "/usr/local/site-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py", line 64, in decode
options, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 115, in decode
key, algorithms)
File "/usr/local/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 177, in _verify_signature
if not alg_obj.verify(signing_input, key, signature):
File "/usr/local/site-packages/jwt/algorithms.py", line 138, in verify
return constant_time_compare(sig, self.sign(msg, key))
File "/usr/local/site-packages/jwt/compat.py", line 50, in constant_time_compare
result |= ord(x) ^ ord(y)
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

It's clear the error is generated from inside the module code.

Any idea what's causing this error?

Thanks

Comment: What is the type of "encoded" and "secret" variables? It looks like it's trying to get ASCII code from a list of ints instead of a list of chars

Comment: "encoded" is `bytes`, and "secret" is `str`.
This is the value of "encoded": `b'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzb21lIjoicGF5bG9hZCJ9.4twFt5NiznN84AWoo1d7KO1T_yoc0Z6XOpOVswacPZg'`

Answer (score 0):

PyJWT doesn't support python 3.2, pyJWT uses `hmac.compare_digest` to verify signatures which was added in Python 3.3, it gets around this by reimplementing compare_digest for Python 2 however the re-implementation doesnt support python 3.2 since indexing into a bytes object returns a character in python 2 and an int in python 3.

[source](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/issues/206)